# Cant navigate between screens that has react-navigation-fluid-transitions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am making a application in react native and found [FluidTransitions](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions) library to have some animation and such. And I also need [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html) to navigate between screens. The problem i have is that I am unable to navigate between 2 screens that has transitions, i get this error:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\AnimatedEvent.js:94:46 in AnimatedEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\AnimatedImplementation.js:504:42 in event
- ... 37 more stack frames from framework internals
```

But there is no problem to navigate between a "normal" screen (that has no transitions) and a screen with transitions.

App.tsx

```
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Test1 from "./views/TestOne"
import Test2 from "./views/TestTwo"

const store = createStore()
configure({ enforceActions: "always" })

export default observer(() => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ isReady: false })

    const AppSwitchNavigator = FluidNavigator({
        screen1: { screen: Test1 },
        screen2: { screen: Test2 },
    })

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
            <AppContainer />
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )
})
```

TestOne.tsx

```
<TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={1}
    style={styles.container}
    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('screen2')}>
    <Transition shared='paper'>
        <View style={styles.paper} />
    </Transition>
    <Transition appear='horizontal'>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>THE TEN</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subheader}>AIR JORDAN I</Text>
        </View>
    </Transition>
    <Transition shared='shoe'>
        <Image style={styles.shoe} source={require('../../assets/img/shoe.png')} />
    </Transition>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

package.json

```
"react-navigation": "^3.0.0",
"react-navigation-fluid-transitions": "^0.3.2",
```

Comment: Where is `_callListeners ` ?

Comment: @hongdevelop it´s from node modules so not something i can change